# Typescript strongly typed endpoints

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to strongly type API endpoints in a front end client. Here is the code I have so far.

```
type URI<T extends string> = { url: T }
type QUERY<T> = { query: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | T[K][] } }
type DATA<T> = { data: Required<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] }> }
type PATCHDATA<T> = { data: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } }
type RESPONSE<T> = { response: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } }
type ENDPOINT = URI<any> & Partial<QUERY<any> & DATA<any> & PATCHDATA<any> & RESPONSE<any>>;

type GET<T extends ENDPOINT> = T
type POST<T extends ENDPOINT> = T;

type GET_ACCOUNT = GET<DATA<{}> & URI<'account/:id'> & QUERY<{ userId: string }> & RESPONSE<{}>>
type GET_ACCOUNTS = GET<URI<'accounts'> & QUERY<{ firstName: string, lastName: string }> & RESPONSE<{ id: string, firstname: string, lastName: string }>>

type CREATE_ACCOUNT = POST<QUERY<{}> & URI<'accounts'> & DATA<{}> & RESPONSE<{}>>

type GETS = GET_ACCOUNT | GET_ACCOUNTS
type POSTS = CREATE_ACCOUNT 

type ACCOUNT_ENDPOINTS = GETS | POSTS
```

***Question***: How do I throw a compiler error when trying to add DATA to a GET endpoint? in `GET_ACCOUNT` where it says `GET<DATA<{}>>`, that should show a red squiggly line and say something along the lines of 'A GET request can't have a data property' or something. I've tried various versions of OMIT<> and EXCLUDE<>

```
attempts

type GET<T extends Omit<ENDPOINT, 'data'> = T

type GET<T extends Pick<ENDPOINT, Exclude<keyof ENDPOINT, 'data'>>> = T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slighty similar to @kelsny's answer

I used an intersection along with a condition type for a slightly clearer error message

```
type POST<T extends ENDPOINT & T extends QUERY<any> ? "Query not allowed in POST" : unknown > = T
```

and the below line will throw an error

```
type CREATE_ACCOUNT= POST<QUERY<{}> & URI<'accounts'> & DATA<{}> & RESPONSE<{}>>
```

> Type 'QUERY<{}> & URI<"accounts"> & DATA<{}> & RESPONSE<{}>' does not satisfy the constraint '"Query not allowed in POST"'.ts(2344)

that way I can still change the properties on QUERY without affecting POST if need be

Comment: Now how might I do this with multiple conditional types as in type                           
    POST<T extends ENDPOINT & 
    T extends QUERY<any> ? "Query not allowed in POST" : 
    T extends PATCHDATA<any> ? "Query not allowed in POST" : unknown> = T

Answer (score 2):

You can intersect `ENDPOINT` with another type to prevent `DATA` from being added:

```
type GET<T extends ENDPOINT & { data?: "GET requests cannot have DATA" }> = T
```

I have chosen `{ data?: "GET requests cannot have DATA" }` as the type because the error message provided is mildly helpful:

> Type 'DATA<{}> & URI<"account/:id"> & QUERY<{ userId: string; }> & RESPONSE<{}>' does not satisfy the constraint 'URI & Partial<QUERY & DATA & PATCHDATA & RESPONSE> & { data?: "GET requests cannot have DATA" | undefined; }'. Type 'DATA<{}> & URI<"account/:id"> & QUERY<{ userId: string; }> & RESPONSE<{}>' is not assignable to type '{ data?: "GET requests cannot have DATA" | undefined; }'.
> Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
> **Type 'Required<{}>' is not assignable to type '"GET requests cannot have DATA"'.(2344)**

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-RTA-IWBYkiRJpEALZrYhkShUAA0UA4kVrDabUdbsee8cRSYMEeb0fbUGrpBIOF7kZb1A7XZ7jcXk-FqZ1PjEFWGQSkhuNpvNL3Gsp+0iDybtiEdztd7uApfB1tvcdGCaRt+3acZuYWrix5ZuSLgZie2YjGmMo5mE+5SIeIGnmgGK7tAmYofqKpknBQFwS4sHQUIQA)